# How do I permanently delete, not erase, disk0s4 from Terminal?

Tags: terminal, disk-utility

I would like to use Terminal because whenever I use Disk Utility and I click partition, Disk Utility crashes.

What command should I use in Terminal to permanently delete disk0s4, not erase?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. An edit to show `diskutil list` might helo us help you with a specific command. As you astutely commented, erasing a partition isn’t the same as removing a partition. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/304889/5472

Comment: To remove the partition, use ```diskutil eraseVolume free none /dev/disk0s4```. To expand other partition, it depends on what filesystem do you use. For example, for apfs, a simple ```diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk1 0``` will do.